# 404 Item not found When Providing access to existing documents from an XPage View

Tags: xpages

I have been following the tutorial [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Designer+Tutorial#action=openDocument&res_title=Providing_access_to_existing_documents_ddt853&content=pdcontent) for creating an XPage application. Unfortunately I am encountering an `Error 404 HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception` when you try to follow a link to another document from the main view XPage. Everything else seems to function properly until that point.

It happens when you select "XPage associated with the documents form".

According to some googling I simply needed to rebuild my project but that didn't work. That was the only fix I was able to find.

The link for my xpage for my view is : `http://localhost/ExpenseClaims.nsf/xclaimsview.xsp`
The link to a xpage with the 404 error from my view is: `http://localhost/ExpenseClaims.nsf/%24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp?documentId=15DA9966C77908D385257C150070483D&action=openDocument`

The problem has returned for my "claim" xpage that represents a form document named "claim". My response documents open as needed.

My associations are:
Views:     Xpage:
Claims ->   xclaimsView
Forms:     Xpage:
claim ->    claim
response -> response

Comment: Did you create an XPage with the same name as form name of selected document?

Comment: Amend your question with the page source AND the two urls: the one that shows your page and the one throwing the 404

Comment: I was not the same name initially so I changed it to the same name after encountering the error with no success.

Comment: So do you have a form and an XPage with the same name? Or did you edit your form properties? In any case you might have run into a cache that prevented the solution to work on Friday?

Comment: When the corrisponding xpage was created it had a diffrent name from it's form. I ran into this problem so I changed the names to be the same. It did not initially fix the problem but it is working as expected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the connection between your XPage and the form didn't work. Open the form, then in the properties pick the XPage you want to open. Save it and try again. 
There's one special case when you have an XPage with the same name as the form, where that should happen automatically, but it is safer if you specify the property in the form (second tab on the property box)

Comment: What did you mean with "this"? a) having an XPage with the same name or b) put the name of the XPage into the form property? Anyway: if you want to display different XPages based on some properties of documents that used the same form, then you should compute your XPage name in the data source properties

Comment: if you elaborate more on "using reponse docs" you can be pointed in the right direction

Comment: B works but the tutorial says:  
`Ensure that the runtime target is the XPage associated with the document's form.
This means that clicking on a document whose form is main opens the main XPage, and (later) clicking on a document whose form is response opens the response XPage.`

Comment: So? That works as designed. When you set "Open XPage associated with the form" then any association will be honoured. Nobody stops you to associate the same XPage to multiple forms. If you on the other hand have one form that should use different XPages based on content (e.g. if it as a response, an older version), then you have to compute the XPage name. - Feel free to accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

The data connection from the xpage to the form seems to be breaking down that's a possible cause but not an acceptable answer. The reasons are everything from the project build being broken to the port that domino designer is using as default being occupied.

Cleaning then building the project may help (Project -> Clean) but in my case it didn't. Opening the Page by selecting it by name is helpful but not if you are opening two different pages from the same view(View Properties -> at run time  open selected document). There was another suggestion that said to move the default domino test port(File -> Preferences -> Domino Designer) but that didn't work for me.

The final answer was to go to each form's properties box and link it to it's corresponding xpage (second tab form properties). (see answer marked as correct for a link to IBM with a better explanation)